# Exponent of a number in a product

Tags: java

I've encountered this problem on homework, we have to find the exponent of a given number(int) in a product of numbers(one-hundered long numbers). The problem is, we are not allowed to use the class BigInteger. I tried two aproaches, however both failed:

1. I wanted to store the prime factorisation of the given number(int-range) and then easily check for prime occurences in the list of long numbers. This method works for small numbers, but numbers close to 2**32 is not very efficient.
2. I looked for the gcd of the given number and every number in the list and if the gcd divided the given number then I divided them and then stored the gcd, do the same for the next number, found the gcd, multiplied it with the previous(possibly "leftover" gcd), etc. This method failed because when I look for gcd and for the 50th time I only find a factor of the given number, it's range is over the range of long.

Could someone please give me an advice on how to proceed or how to solve these obstacles.

I work in JAVA.

Comment: If you post some code, we might be able to tell you how to avoid it going wrong.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem. Are you trying to find the exponent of the number that results from multiplying the 100 numbers together, or are you trying to find the exponent of the 100 numbers individually? Could you provide an example of the sort of thing you're trying to solve?

Comment: Stackoverflow is teeming with homeworks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is given, and what is to be expected?

Comment: http://goo.gl/PGH7jU I have to find the exponent of the given number in the product of these numbers, i.e. for 10 it should return 103

Comment: @David I still do not understand your question, and your link only works with a access rights. I am 100% sure I can answer your question if only you can clearly state what you want.

Comment: @user3437460 There's a given text document consisting of roughly 100 integers in the range long, separated by white spaces and a positive integer in the range int. Our goal is to find the exponent of the given positive integer in the product of the integers in the given text document i.e. to find how many times does the given positive integer evenly divide the product of the numbers in the text document.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is basic math, but lets give you an anwer:

first you factorize the small given number, lets call it **a**. Now you have **a** as a factor of primes (with some kind of exponents).

Now you have to find out the exponents of these primes in the big number. Because they are primes, you can do this by finding the exponents in the factors of the product that you have and adding them together!

you'll do something like this:

```
// input from previous step
int[] a_primes;
int[] a_exponents;
int[] factors_of_b;

// output to next step
int[] b_exponents = new int[a_primes.length];

for (int i = 0; i < b_exponents.length; i ++) {
  b_exponents = 0
}

for (int factor : factors_of_b) {
  for (int i; i < a_primes.length; i++) {
    if (factor % a_primes[i] == 0) {
      factor /= a_primes[i];
      b_exponents[i]++;
    }
  }
}
```

After this you have the exponents of every prime in **b**, that's also in a. Now you only need to find out how many times **b**'s primes contain **a**'s primes.

For that you'd do a minimum search:

```
// input from prevous step
int[] a_primes;
int[] a_exponents;
int[] b_exponents;

// final result
int result = b_exponents[0] / a_exponents[0];

for (int i = 0; i < a_primes.length; i++) {
  int x = b_exponents[i] / a_exponents[i];
  if (x < result) {
    result = x;
  }
}
```

And there you have it. This is just pseudo code, no error checking done, just yo you're clear on the concept.

Comment: This is the method 1. I described, but this method failed for large numbers; factoring large numbers takes very long. Because the given number ranges in int, and numbers close to 2**32 take too long to factorise.